# Pushwoosh - Send notification to specific device

Tags: cordova, push, pushwoosh

just wanted to ask if it is possible to send push notifications to a specific device with a free account? 
Means, that i´ve got 10 subscribers, and i wanted to send a notification to subscriber 2, later then to subscriber 9 and so on..
Or do i need a payed version? Because i read something that i need the pushwoosh api, but there is nothing like this in the free version?!
Is there a way to do this? Or maybe an other service that offers this for free? 
Would be great! 
Paying isn´t really an option.. i don´t make money with my app, it´s just for me and my friends.. just 10 people..

Thanks!

Comment: the app was build with cordova by the way

Comment: As far as I can see so far, this isn't an option in the paid versions either...

Comment: Okay I found it. To do it in the paid version, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155644/how-to-send-push-notification-to-some-specific-users-using-pushwoosh-web-api-in

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible via Pushwoosh Free account. However, I am not sure whether  this functionality is available on a Free plan of any service at all, expect for Parse, perhaps. I guess, you should check their pricing.